# Does the Google Maps iOS SDK v1.3 support tile overlays in front of the native map text?

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

So I've added a custom tile overlay to a Google Map on iOS using a subclass of [GMSSyncTileLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_sync_tile_layer).  The problem I'm running into is that Google's native labels on the map (e.g. the names of buildings, streets etcetera) are being positioned above my tile overlay and are interfering visually with my tile imagery.  I see that `GMSSyncTileLayer` has a `zIndex` property, but this appears to only affect where one overlay is positioned relative to another, not where an overlay is positioned relative to the native map text.

Is there some way to bring a tile overlay right to the front, even in front of the native map text?  If there isn't I'll file a feature request, but wanted to check here first whether I'd simply missed something.

Comment: i have seen many zindex related posts. I think it would be benefical to 'fix' this to be more flexible here

Answer (score 0):

no. the intrinsic order is not changeable and it is IIRC(!):

- map
- overlays
- text
- markers

#### My idea for a feature request:

maybe the order shouldn't just be defined by a zindex but also be controlled by something that is known on windows and mac and x-window as the **window level**

it defines what the base index for a specific element is...
e.g. there'd be 4 levels here:

- map level
- overlays level
- text level
- markers level

for any GMSOverlay you could set its level.
If not specified, it would act as it does now.

```
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithDefaults];
NSLog(@"%@", marker.overlayLevel);
==> '4' GMSOverlayLevelMarkers

marker.level = GMSOverlayLevelMap
NSLog(@"%@", marker.overlayLevel);
==> '4' GMSOverlayLevelMap
==> it would be behind text and overlays
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can disable the background map with `[yourMapView setMapType:kGMSTypeNone]`. This will improve your overlay download performance too, because the background tiles aren't downloaded.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue with this approach is that when the custom tile overlay only covers a certain portion of the map, and it's desirable to have the rest of the map display the regular imagery, this method is not suitable.